# How to make id in jpa-entity with String type?

Tags: spring, jpa

Used spring+jpa.
There is entity, that contains id and field name with String type:

```
@Entity
class Customer{

 @id
 String id;

 String name;
...
}
```

if id - field type int - everything okey.

if id is Srting type:
SQLSyntaxErrorException: Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes

Used MySQL database.

```
create table riskmetric (id integer not null, name varchar(255), primary key (id)) engine=MyISAM
```

Comment: and what is the defintion of the associated table for that class? i.e the DDL

Comment: @BillyFrost there is only hello world program for this time, so, there is just entity with two fields - id and name.

Comment: which doesnt answer the question. WHAT IS THE DATABASE TABLE defined as? column types, lengths, nullability etc. Your JPA provider likely created the table for you if you didnt create it first

Comment: @BillyFrost yes, I used create-drop, so, after application will start, this table will created by application(not by hands)

Comment: so are you going to tell us what the database table is defined as ? (In the JPA provider log, or obtainable from your database). Otherwise there is nothing to say here

Comment: @BillyFrost  Hibernate: create table riskmetric (id integer not null, name varchar(255), primary key (id)) engine=MyISAM

Comment: delete the table and create it again ... the PK is not an INT, so you need to recreate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way you can create generatable id of String type:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
@Column(name = "PR_KEY")
private String prKey;
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved by using @Column

```
@Id
@Column(length = 10)
private String id;
```

Comment: which is not answering your question. You said "make id of String type". An "int" is not a String type.